# Creating a functions to avoid loops

Tags: r, function, loops, coordinates, gis

Can anyone highlight areas here that could be turned into a function? And if so, how? 
Are there general rules for writing a function or writing cleaner scripts? 
Can anyone see any red flag bad habits in this script?

Example context:

The aim of this script is to run through track coordinates. For each location I want to generate 9 random samples within a designated error field. For each location error and the original point (10 in total) I wish to extract data from a source. In this case distance from a shape file. I then want to take the mean of the extracted data and add it back onto the original track file.

Example data:

```
Date_Time           longitude       latitude 
27/10/2011 15:15    -91.98876953    1.671900034 
30/10/2011 14:31    -91.91790771    1.955003262 
30/10/2011 15:34    -91.91873169    1.961261749 
30/10/2011 20:55    -91.86060333    1.996331811 
31/10/2011 04:03    -91.67115021    1.929548025 
03/11/2011 18:36    -90.67552948    1.850875616 
04/11/2011 18:26    -90.65361023    1.799352288 
07/11/2011 19:29    -92.13287354    0.755102754 
07/11/2011 20:28    -92.13739014    0.783674061 
27/12/2011 13:43    -88.16407776    -4.953748703
07/01/2012 18:44    -82.51725006    -5.717019081
07/01/2012 19:30    -82.50763702    -5.706347942
07/01/2012 20:28    -82.50556183    -5.696153641 
07/01/2012 21:10    -82.50305176    -5.685819626
08/01/2012 00:27    -82.18003845    -5.623015404 
08/01/2012 18:37    -82.17269897    -5.61870575 
08/01/2012 19:20    -82.16355133    -5.612465382
```

This data represents one file of which there will be many in a list.

Example script to achieve task:

```
#### Packages ####

library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(truncnorm) 

# Load files

dir <- 'C:/Users/Documents/PhD/Chapters/'
sfolder <- paste0(dir, 'Data/Tracks/')
sfiles <- list.files(sfolder , '.csv', recursive = TRUE)

## Load the contours for proximity measurements 
# 200
contour2 <- readOGR(paste0(dir, 'QGIS/Base layers/2GEBCO_2020_Contour_200.gpkg'))

# 1000
contour1 <- readOGR(paste0(dir, 'QGIS/Base layers/2GEBCO_2020_Contour_1000.gpkg'))

# Land 
land <- readOGR(paste0(dir, 'QGIS/Base layers/GEBCO_2020_Contour_0.gpkg'))

# List of contours to extract 
extracts <- c('200','1000', '0')

# Extract proximity data for all tracks 

for (o in 1:length(sfiles))
{
  # o <- 1

tagType <- dirname(dirname(dirname((sfiles [o])))) # gives 'ARGOS' or 'PSAT' 
track <- read.csv(paste0(sfold , sfiles [o]))
ntrack <- nrow(track)

# Create data frame for proximity measures
proximity <-  data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = ntrack))

# Generate random samples of each point 

for(i in 1:nrow(track))
{
  # i <- 1
  errors <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 10))

  if(tagType == 'PSAT')
  {
    meanx <- mean(track$longitude[i]-0.53, track$longitude[i]+0.53)
    meany <- mean(track$latitude[i]-1.08, track$latitude[i]+1.08)
    errors[,1] <-  rnorm(n=10, a=track$longitude[i]-0.53, b=track$longitude[i]+0.53, meanx)
    errors[,2] <- rtruncnorm(n=10, a=track$latitude[i]-1.08, b=track$latitude[i]+1.08, meany)
  }

  if(tagType == 'ARGOS')
  {
    meanx <- mean(track$longitude[i]-0.12, track$longitude[i]+0.12)
    meany <- mean(track$latitude[i]-0.12, track$latitude[i]+0.12)
    errors[,1] <-  rtruncnorm(n=10, a=track$longitude[i]-0.12, b=track$longitude[i]+0.12, meanx)
    errors[,2] <- rtruncnorm(n=10, a=track$latitude[i]-0.12, b=track$latitude[i]+0.12, meany)
  } 

errors[1,] <- c(track$longitude[i],track$latitude[i])  
colnames(errors) <- c('longitude', 'latitude')
errTrack <- SpatialPoints(errors[,c(1,2)])


# Now to get coordinates from contour files 

for(a in 1:length(extracts))
{
  # a <- 2
  extract <- extracts[a]

  if(extract == '200')
  { contour <- contour2 }
  if(extract == '1000')
  { contour <- contour1 }
  if(extract == '0')
  { contour <- land }

n <- length(errTrack) # 10 for 9 random samples + original location 
distances <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = n))

for (e in seq_along(errTrack)) {
  distances[e,] <- coordinates(gNearestPoints(errTrack[e], contour))[2,]
}

allDist <- as.data.frame(distances)
colnames(allDist) <- c('longitude', 'latitude')


# Create objects with error lat/long and nearest contour lat/long

p1 <- cbind(errTrack$longitude, errTrack$latitude)
p2 <- cbind(allDist$longitude, allDist$latitude)

# Convert to Great Circle distance 

finalDist <- as.data.frame(distHaversine(p1, p2, r=6378137)/1000)
colnames(finalDist) <- 'distance'
finalDist <- finalDist %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2)

distValue <- mean(finalDist$distance)

proximity[i,a] <- distValue

} # end for all contour extracts
} # end for each row in track 

track$Proximity_land <- proximity$X3
track$Proximity_200m <- proximity$X1
track$Proximity_1000m <- proximity$X2

} # end for all tracks
```

I know this may be a little niche, but if anyone is able to offer any insight into general ways to clean up looping code with functions, or if anyone can direct me to resources that might help, it would be much appreciated. Equally if anyone can specifically help with speeding up/ cleaning up this code it would be amazing! (contour files can be a random polygon for the sake reproduction if needed).
I hope this question is suitable for this forum, apologies if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your assessment that the code could clarified by making use of some functions.  By using functions you can break up large, complicated programs into manageable chunks that can reasoned about individually.

With regards to the loops in the program, many people find maps to be clearer alternative to loops.  They essentially iterate over a collection of elements as you would do in a loop, but without having to track index variable.  The purrr package provides an excellent collection of maps and other functions.

Some good resources for reading about these topics and more include https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/, https://r4ds.had.co.nz/, and https://adv-r.hadley.nz/.

In the code below, I attempted to extract some of the code into functions in the hope of making the control flow easier to follow.  Since I haven't tried the code on actual data, it surely won't work without some fixes, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.

```r
calc_errors_psat <- function(long, lat) {
  calc_errTrack(long, lat, 0.53, 1.08)
}

calc_errors_argos <- function(long, lat) {
  calc_errTrack(long, lat, 0.12, 0.12)
}

calc_errTrack <- function(long, lat, long_offset, lat_offset) {
  # don't `meanx` and `meany` have the same as value as `long` and `lat`?
  meanx <- mean(long - long_offset, long + long_offset)
  meany <- mean(lat - lat_offset, lat + lat_offset)
  err_long <- rtruncnorm(n=10, a=long-long_offset, b=long+long_offset, meanx)
  err_lat <- rtruncnorm(n=10, a=lat-lat_offset, b=lat+lat_offset, meany)
  err <- data.frame(
    longitude = c(long, err_long),
    latitude  = c(lat, err_lat)
  )
  SpatialPoints(err)
}

calc_distValues <- function(errTrack, contour) {

  n <- length(errTrack) # 10 for 9 random samples + original location 
  distances <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = n))

  for (e in seq_along(errTrack)) {
    distances[e,] <- coordinates(gNearestPoints(errTrack[e], contour))[2,]
  }

  allDist <- as.data.frame(distances)
  colnames(allDist) <- c('longitude', 'latitude')


  # Create objects with error lat/long and nearest contour lat/long

  p1 <- cbind(errTrack$longitude, errTrack$latitude)
  p2 <- cbind(allDist$longitude, allDist$latitude)

  # Convert to Great Circle distance 

  finalDist <- as.data.frame(distHaversine(p1, p2, r=6378137)/1000)
  colnames(finalDist) <- 'distance'
  finalDist <- finalDist %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2)

  mean(finalDist$distance)
}

find_err_fcn <- function(loc) {
  tagType <- dirname(dirname(dirname(loc)))
  if (tagType == "PSAT") {
    calc_errors_psat
  } else {
    calc_errors_argos
  }
}

# get the track file locations
dir <- 'C:/Users/Documents/PhD/Chapters/'
sfolder <- file.path(dir, 'Data/Tracks')
track_locs <- list.files(sfolder, full.names = TRUE)

# read in files and error functions into a data frame, and calculate the track
# errors
track_df <- tibble::tibble(
  track_list    = purrr::map(track_locs, read.csv),
  calc_err_fcns = purrr::map(track_locs, find_err_fcn),
  errTrack_list = purrr::map2(track_list, calc_err_fcns, function(x, f) f(x))
)

# calculate the track proximities distances
proximity_contours <- c(
  contour2 = readOGR(file.path(dir, 'QGIS/Base layers/2GEBCO_2020_Contour_200.gpkg')),
  contour1 = readOGR(file.path(dir, 'QGIS/Base layers/2GEBCO_2020_Contour_1000.gpkg')),
  land     = readOGR(file.path(dir, 'QGIS/Base layers/GEBCO_2020_Contour_0.gpkg'))
)

track_results <- purrr::map_dfc(
  .x = proximity_contours,
  .f = function(contour) purrr::map(
    .x      = track_df$errTrack_list,
    .f      = calc_distValue,
    contour = contour
  )
)
```

Comment: This looks really amazing and interesting. I will try to work through it, but it will take some time to explore what you have suggested and what it means in context.This is just what I needed; an example to work though with my own data set. Thank you!

Comment: Note that I made an edit to correct two function calls that I had mistakenly written as `calc_errors` to `calc_errTrack`.

Comment: One other aside: it's usually not advised to perform rounding in your numerical routine directly, if that is for printing purposes then you can do some modification of the object produced by your routine in a separate step.